# Определить площадь фигуры

Tags: java

Не могу разобраться с задачей, помогите пожалуйста:

Дано N прямоугольников со сторонами, параллельными осям координат. Требуется
определить площадь фигуры, образованной объединением данных прямоугольников.

**Входные данные**
Входной файл (первый параметр вызова), в котором идет N строк, содержащих по 4 числа: x1,
y1, x2, y2 - координаты двух противоположных углов прямоугольника. Все координаты –
целые числа, не превосходящие по абсолютной величине 10 000. (1 <= N <= 100)

**Выходные данные**
В выходной файл (второй параметр вызова) выведите одно целое число – площадь фигуры.

**Дополнительные условия**
● Объем используемой памяти не должен превышать 16мб.
● Должна быть проверка на корректность передаваемых параметров (args[]).
● Должна быть проверка input.txt на корректность формата.

Comment: Вы предлагаете за вас написать код для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Хотелось бы каких то примеров.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы мы придумали вам алгоритм, или у вас есть проблемы в реализации конкретного алгоритма?

Comment: Помнится, зимой на сборах у нас одна из первых задач была практически такой же. Только у нас были бутерброды, падающие на пол, надо было сказать площадь, занятую ими, при том, что они могли частично падать друг на друга. Могу объяснить решение, оно довольно простое, но хотелось бы узнать у вас, что вы уже придумали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После 10 минут раздумья мне пришла идея:

A1, A2,... An - прямоугольники

тогда площадь объединения можно так считать:

S(A1 U A2 U ... U An) = S(A1) + S(A2) + ... + S(An) -S(A1 ^ A2) -S(A2 ^ A3) - .. (-1)^(n-1)*S(A1^A2^...^An))

где A1^A2 - Пересечение прямоугольника A1 c прямоугольником A2

Т.е. **Площадь пересечение** это сумма площадей минус **сумма всевозможных пересечений по два** плюс сумма всевозможных пересечений по три и т.д.

Про java:

1) [Работа с файлами](http://kek.ksu.ru/EOS/Java/gl4_3.html)

2) [Работа с аргументами командной строки](http://www.dokwork.ru/2012/09/parsing-command-line-arguments.html.html)